# Should I start to use DX11

Tags: directx, directx11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [learning Direct3D 9, 10 or 11 ?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/learning-direct3d-9-10-or-11)

I have just started game dev and was wondering should I use DX11 or version 10?

I know AMD/nVidia now have DX11 cards but there are not many games using them now.

So should I wait untill they are mainstearm?

Comment: Possibly related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/learning-direct3d-9-10-or-11

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/learning-direct3d-9-10-or-11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends what you want to use it for. If you just want to play with new features and learn stuff, go right ahead! Whatever you do will be useful in the future.

If you're aiming to sell software, and want to have a large target market, it might not be the best move right now. According to [steam hardware survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey), only about 5% of users have dx11-capable systems, while over 50% have dx10 now. Keep in mind though that this is survey of steam users, who more likely have gaming-capable PCs, so the total market situation is probably worse.

Comment: He "just started game dev", so by the time he's ready to ship a game/put it on the internet, DX11 is likely to be mainstream.

Comment: You know what's scary? If you look at the survey now only 4 months later, DX11 hardware has 41% share on Steam.

Comment: Well, that's 41% of vista or win7 users, but the increase is still rather massive.

Answer (score 4):

Use DX11. You can target DX10 and DX9 feature levels from DX11 so when you're ready, you can use the additional DX11 features.